# JQuery Bassistance Form Email-check using remote

Tags: php, jquery, validation, email-validation

I'm using the JQuery Bassistance Form Validation plugin, and everything works fine until I try to check for existing e-mails in my MySQL database.

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#signup').validate({
    rules: {
            email: {
            required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: "email_check.php"
        }//end remote
        }//end email
    },//end rules
    messages: {
        email: {
            remote: "Email already in use."
        }//end email
    } //end messages
    }); //end validate

    }); //end ready
```

And here is my email_check.php file:

```
    <? php

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'step1_db')
    or die('Error connecting to the database');

    $email = $_GET['email'];

    $check_email = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
    $existing = mysqli_query($dbc, $check_email);
    $num_rows = $existing->num_rows;    

    if ($num_rows == 1){
    echo json_encode(FALSE);

    }else{

    echo json_encode(TRUE);
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);

    ?>
```

So right now, if I try to input an e-mail that exists in the database into my form, I get the default error message for invalid e-mail, and not the "Email already in use." Even if I input a valid e-mail that does not exist in the database, the error message doesn't go away.

I'm guessing the problem is in my php file... I've tried using 'return true' and 'return false' but they also did not work. I changed my code to echo json_encode(FALSE) from answers to similar topics as this one.
Would anyone be able to put a finger on what's going on here?

Comment: what is the raw response that you see when you check the console?

Comment: I know this might just be a quick example setup, but in case it's not I want to point out that you should really be validating that user input before you put it into your query.

Comment: I actually think that the problem might be with what the javascript validation is expecting as a return value. `json_econde(true)` just returns the string `"true"`.

Comment: thank you for the reply, ogc-nick!
By validating, do you mean using mysql_real_escape_string()?
Also, how can I check the raw response from the console?
Sorry, I'm really new to this, so my knowledge is really limited to the very basics books and tutorials teach me :(

Comment: also, I've tried using return true/false, but my problem stays the same.

Comment: in firefox or chrome right click and 'inspect element' then view the 'console' tab. this will help you a lot in debugging your code. mysql_real_escape_string() is a good place to start and should definitely be used at the very least.

Comment: Check the value of $_GET['email']. According to the documentation the index will match the name of the element.

Comment: Try returning a string. The documentation says that a string is treated as a FALSE and that string will be shown to the user as the error message.

Comment: thanks for the pointers!
So the console gave me this error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - and it pointed out my email_check.php

Comment: Also if you happen to already have more than 1 matching email in your table, then you conditonal `==1` will fail so use `>0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options):

> The serverside resource is called via $.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and gets
>   a key/value pair, corresponding to the name of the validated element
>   and its value as a GET parameter. The response is evaluated as JSON
>   and must be true for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined
>   or null for invalid elements, using the default message; or a string,
>   eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as
>   the error message.

It looks then like you are responding correctly. It looks like your path to the file is wrong since you are getting a 404 error in the console. FIx the path and the rest looks good.

Comment: thanks once again! Seems like  I don't get an error now, but the problem with the error message not showing is still there. If I fill the input with anything, I get the default error "Please enter a valid email address"

Answer (score 1):

Your php file has email variable set to GET, while the remote validate function is set to POST, change one or the other to match and you should be set

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much Jay Rizzi, that was it! I wish I could give you and ogc-nick reputation for helping me so much, but it's going to have to wait until I have 15 points myself... :)